# thoughts on global variable with multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, global-variables

I'm using global variables in my web application. The web application does have a log-in and can allow multiple users. The global variables are used to store data for the items currently being processed.

Will my application be in chaos if multiple users tried to access these global variables or will it be just global in their respective workstation?

If it will create chaos, what's the best way to replace the global variables.

Comment: An example of the code and usage would be helpful.

Comment: You need to distinguish between application state and session state variables. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178594(v=vs.100).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `...or will it be just global in their respective workstation?` You seriously need to catch up on how ASP.NET works. No C# runs on the workstation, it all runs on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `static` variables in your ASP.NET application! They are shared across all sessions / users since they are kept in the web server, not on clients!

You have a few options, built-in already in ASP.NET:

- [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache(v=vs.110).aspx): application-wide, all-sessions, for temporary objects
- [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx): per-session
- [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx): application-wide, all sessions, for long time keep objects

You can easily create a property in a class that uses one of those (of course you could do this without properties, but I think they are a better practice):

```
public List<string> SomeSettingPerUser
{
    get
    {
        return (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeSetting"];
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeSetting"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, does this include the variables inside my class? eg: Private static OracleConnection oconn. Also should i remove the static word whenever i create a function inside a class? eg. public static void BindList(). Removing the static word makes the function unaccessible.

Comment: Those variables are shared too. It is safe to use static methods.